# Using Meteor upsert with $inc

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, upsert

I am struggling to get Meteor's collection.upsert method to work properly. Here is what I have:

```
const tagStatsId = TagStats.upsert({
  tag: tag
}, { 
  $inc: { count: 1 },
  $setOnInsert: { tag: tag, count: 0 }
});
```

I also have an upsert method to decrease the count by 1 (this could probably be an update method instead):

```
tagStatsId = TagStats.upsert({ 
  tag: tag 
}, { 
  $inc: { 
    count: -1,
  }
});
```

Right now, both methods are returning 0 for their result, which per the meteor docs should be an object. I am at a loss for why these methods aren't behaving properly.

It's worth noting I'm calling this method from a denormalizer method which fires after another object insert, but I don't think that should affect the behavior at all. I'm also using mdg:validated-method, but again, I don't think that should affect anything.

Comment: Can you tell a bit more how exactly your code is not behaving properly? What's the expected vs observed result? BTW, [meteor documentation](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-upsert) states that `upsert` should return an object containing `numberAffected` and `insertedId` keys, not a document id.

Comment: Sure, the result being returned was a 0 every time....this is the expected behavior on a failed update operation, not an upsert call. I also tried replacing the upsert call with a simple insert just to confirm the rest of my code (imports, method calls, etc) was working properly, and it worked perfectly. This is seeming more and more like a bug, but I wanted to ask here first.